# ¿Se puede hacer que funcione SweetAlert al hacer clic en un texto?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert

Estoy haciendo una página web, y hasta ahora utilizaba los alert de JS.

Había realizado un texto, y, al hacer clic me saltaba un alert. Era de este tipo:

```
<a href Onclick="alert("Texto")">Haz click aquí</a>
```

Y quiero saber si se puede hacer con SweetAlert.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: podrias hacer una funcion que escuche el click en el texto con JS y solamente lantas la funcion de SweetAlert y listo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pareceria usarlo asi, de esta manera no combinas tu codigo js con el html

```js
$("#tagA").on("click", function (){
    swal({
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        title: 'Titulo',
        html: "Texto",
        type: 'success',
    })  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.25.6/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="tagA">A</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar Jquery para escuchar un click en el texto de la siguiente manera:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
     $(".text").click(function(){
  alert("hola");
      //swal("Hello world!");
  
      });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  
  <title>ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p class="text">texto ejemplo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

y en vez de ejecutar el alert ejecuta el sawl de sweetalert